# Waking Up in Halacha

Tags: time, sleep, shulchan-aruch

The [first halacha in Shulchan Aruch](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayyim.1.1) debate:

> One should strengthen himself like a lion to get up in the morning to serve his Creator, so that it is he who awakens the dawn. 
>   Rema: At least, one should not delay beyond the time when the congregation prays.

What's the reasoning between this depute?

Comment: I don't see a dispute here.

Comment: @msh210 The SA hold before Amud Hasachar and the Rema holds that he can wake at the time to pray by the Cong. time.

Comment: I don't see that the _Rama_ disagrees that rising before dawn is ideal, and I don't see that the _SA_ says it's forbidden to rise after dawn.

Comment: My guess: When Dovid HaMelch says אָעִירָה שָּׁחַר - is that for everybody to emulate (Shulchan Aruch) or merely for special people (Remo).